# mouseMoved is fired outside NSTrackingArea

Tags: swift, macos, nstrackingarea

I am setting up an `NSTrackingArea` for a specific part of my `NSTextView` in order to have the `mouseMoved` etc methods only to be fired when inside this rect. Here is my code:

```
let rect = ...
let ta = NSTrackingArea(rect: rect,
                     options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeWhenFirstResponder, .inVisibleRect],
                       owner: self,
                    userInfo: nil)
addTrackingArea(ta)
```

However, `mouseMoved` et al. are fired for the whole view.

So my question is: why is mouseMoved fired when the mouse is outside of the tracking area? Is there a mistake in the code above?

**EDIT:**

Apparently, somewhere, a trackingArea is added for the whole view, as I can see in the debug panel:

```
[NSTrackingArea 0x60000212a3f0: rect={{0, 0}, {800, 319.5}}, owner=0x60000390da00 userData=(null)
    NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited NSTrackingMouseMoved 
    NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder
    NSTrackingInVisibleRect 
    installed enabled ]
```

Removing `super.updateTrackingAreas()` does not change this, so something else is going on. I can remove it by using `trackingAreas.forEach { if $0.rect == self.bounds { removeTrackingArea($0)} }`, but it seems to added back when `mouseMoved:` is fired (see the comments).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why is mouseMoved fired when the mouse is outside of the tracking area?

Comment: `NSTextView` implements `mouseMoved:` and sets up a tracking area. When you override `mouseMoved` then your `mouseMoved` is called. Do you want to replace the mouse tracking of `NSTextView` or do you want to add an area?

Comment: I’d like to restrict the mouse tracking to where there is only text. I am using the layoutManager to get the rects for the tracking areas. Even after removing the default tracking area for the whole view, mouseMoved: is called as soon as the cursor enters the text view.

Comment: When and how do you remove the default tracking area? When `mouseMoved:` is fired, are the tracking areas ok or did `rect` change or is an extra area added?

Comment: I remove the default tracking area at the end of `updateTrackingAreas()`. And yes, when `mouseMoved:` is fired, the trackingArea for the complete view is back.

Comment: `NSTextView` also adds an area in `resetCursorRects`. The documentation of the `inVisibleRect` options isn't very clear but I think "The NSTrackingArea object is automatically synchronized with changes in the view’s visible area (visibleRect) and the value returned from rect is ignored." means "the rect is automatically the same as the visible rect".

Comment: Ahh, removing `inVisibleRect` fixed the problem.